# Screwed up Sharepoint links

Tags: channel-entries

We're running EE5.  Some of our links (which go to Sharepoint) contain a string of chars that EE doesn't like, specifically : r : (without the spaces in between.)  Links containing that string look fine in the database, look fine when editing en entry in EE, but then end up being replaced by a bunch of characters when someone views the resulting web page in a browser.  This same string is no problem when coming from a template.  I've searched for answers and had zero luck.  Any help, even a point in the general direction, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you pls. provide more information - what field type you using, how it is looks in front end, do you know any plugins in front end, any extensions which could be effected on it. Because I just tested with ee 5.2.4 and URL fieldtype - everything fine.

Comment: The field type is Rich Text Editor, which I enabled under Add-On Manager.  No third party Add-Ons.  Maybe this was fixed in 5.2.4?  I'm still running 5.1.3.  When I click on my version, it says Up to Date.  I have New version auto check set to Auto - I didn't know there was a newer version.  I'll check it out - thanks!

Comment: Just to add this on: The sharepoint links work in the URL fieldtype on 5.1.3 also.  I just tested it.  Sigh.  I'm still going to perform the upgrade and hope.  But it's not unreasonable that people might want to link to a Sharepoint document inside a text field.  I'll do the update tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: Additional info: Bug reported via GitHub.  In the Rich Text Editor field, certain character combos are being interpreted as emoji short codes, thus messing up any links containing those combos.